# How to "alias" with a bound parameter without breaking pipelining in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I find myself often tacking `|select -first 10` onto the end of commands, and I'd like to shorten that to `|s10`, `|s50`, and a couple other variants. So I'd like to do the equivalent of `set-alias s10 select-object -first 10`.

The standard way you "alias" with bound parameters is to write a function and forward @args along with the extra params. But if I write a function that pipes `$input` through `select-object`, I lose streaming.

I could write a begin/process/end function, but I don't know if/how I can forward each of those to equivalents in select-object. I could write my own begin/process/end implementation of select-object that just implements the -first behavior, but that's just wrong...

(My fallback is to add a tab-completion to expand s10, but I'd really rather learn how I can implement a proper function.)

How can I implement a function that forwards to `select-object` with a parameter I want added but doesn't break pipelining?

Comment: Nice quest. Fingers crossed to see @bruce-payette check this one. He can answer this question for sure

Comment: i think what you want are `proxy functions`. look it up and you will find quite a few folks wanted the same type of thing that you want ... and there are lots of examples online - once you have the `proxy function` search phrase. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this source https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/

In this case, a shortcut/alias for Select-String -First 10, it comes down to:

```
$metadata = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData (Get-Command Select-Object)
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($MetaData) | Out-File -FilePath prxyfunctions.psm1
```

Open the prxyfunctions.psm1 module file and wrap the complete content in the new function called S10

```
function S10 {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'DefaultParameter', HelpUri = 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387', RemotingCapability = 'None')]
    param(

    <abbreviated...>

.ForwardHelpTargetName Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-Object
.ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet

#>
}
```

Then in the Begin{} section add one statement `$PSBoundParameters.Add('First','10')` like below.

```
begin {
        try {
            $outBuffer = $null
            if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer)) {
                $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
            }
            $PSBoundParameters.Add('First','10')
            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-Object', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
            $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
        }
        catch {
            throw
        }
    }
```

That's it. Save the file, import the module, type a nice short command like `gci c:\|s10` and get just 10 results.
If you really want to make things error proof, more coding is needed. If `S10 -First 2` is used you'll get a nice error thrown.

---

**EDIT** in response to @PetSerAl 's useful comments

Some cmdlets further in the pipeline might not be able to handle the proxied function, for instance Sort-Object. Compare the output of these two lines

```
-join (20..1 | Select -First 10 | Sort)
11121314151617181920

-join (20..1 | S10 | Sort)
<nothing>

-join (20..1 | S10 -Wait | Sort)
11121314151617181920
```

It is possible to work around that by using the -Wait parameter on the commandline. Or code the Wait parameter in the proxy function `$PSBoundParameters.Add('Wait',$true)`

When working with large collections this is unfortunate because it disables the Select-Object feature that stops the pipeline after x elements, resulting in more processing and longer waiting.

Comment: Be aware that `SteppablePipeline` does not interact well with `StopUpstreamCommandsException` produced by `Select-Object`. For example: `-join (20..1 | Select-Object -First 10 | Sort-Object)` will produce `11121314151617181920` while `-join (20..1 | S10 | Sort-Object)` produce empty string.

Comment: @PetSerAl Do you know a way to prevent that?

Comment: Simplest workaround would be to use `-Wait`. Other approach would require C# and substantially more code to write.

Comment: Wizardry. I didn't know this proxy generator existed. Useful toy, and I'm content to cut it down to the feature set I need (like I'll just remove its support for -last and so on..). Attaching `-wait` is something I never would have considered either, many thanks for that also.

Answer (score 0):

never use aliases in production scripts is what I would say (and is considered best practice). If its a bit of test code or something quick and dirty that no-one else will ever use, fair enough, but never in production scripts. Aliases can be removed, changed to run other commands and leave you with unintended results as they are user specific.

Comment: I'm well aware of the standard advice on aliases in production scripts

Comment: how about adding a series of variables to your powershell profile?


    # SELECT-OBJECT SHORTCUTS #
    $s10 = Select-Object -First 10
    $s20 = Select-Object -First 20

etc.

Comment: Sounds cool, except it doesn't work. Cannot pipeline through variables or expressions.